# Is it okay to use Pearson or Spearman Correlation when using only one participant's data?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, spearman-rho, kendall-tau

**What I am trying to do?**

Let's assume, I have a data set which consists of only one student's marks of two semesters' courses. In semester 1, he has taken 15 courses and failed to achieve good marks. In semester 2, he has taken the same courses (15 courses) to improve marks. In the data set, there are marks of semester 1 and semester 2 for each of the 15 courses. I want to do a correlate semester 1 marks with semester 2.

As I did not find any assumption of independence in using Pearson or Spearman correlation formula, I thought it's okay to use either of the formulas depending on the satisfaction of all assumptions (e.g. Normality, outlier free in case of Pearson).

**Now, what does create the problem?**

[Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjOxMCW8LroAhVYwTgGHWTvD1IQFjADegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fosf.io%2F8kb2g%2Fdownload&usg=AOvVaw1GIq2zAvwJv60nSNZeKQV6), I found

> However, widely used techniques for correlation, such as simple
>   (ordinary least squares with a single independent variable)
>   regression/***Pearson correlation, assume independence of error
>   between observations*** (Cohen et al., 2003; Howell, 1997; Johnston
>   and DiNardo, 1997). This assumption does not pose a problem if each
>   participant or independent observation is a single data point of
>   paired measures (i.e., two data points corresponding to the same
>   individual such as height and weight).
>
> However, ***the assumption of independence is violated in repeated
>   measures, in which each participant provides more than one data point.***
>   For example, if a study collected height and weight for a sample of
>   people at three time points, there would likely be non-independence in
>   the errors of the three observations belonging to the same person.
>   Analyzing non-independent data with techniques that assume
>   independence is a widespread practice but one that often produces
>   erroneous results (Aarts et al., 2014; Kenny and Judd, 1986; Molenaar,
>   2004).

Moreover, [here](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat509/node/160/) it is mentioned

> The ***correlation*** methods discussed in this chapter ***should be used only
>   with independent data***; ***they should not be applied to repeated measures
>   data where the data are not independent.*** For example, it would not be
>   appropriate to use these measures of correlation to describe the
>   relationship between Week 4 and Week 8 blood pressures in the same
>   patients.

Therefore, I may need to use repeated measures correlation formula.

**What do I think?**

As in my data set, there is only one participant, I may do not need to use repeated measures correlation formula, rather, it can be okay to use general formula of Pearson or Spearman.

**My Question**

Is it okay to use Pearson or Spearman Correlation formula to correlate two variables when each pair of data is from *only one participant*?

Comment: As a measure to describe grades for this one student, Spearman might be OK. Fifteen courses a quarter seems a lot. If some of them are very closely related, correlation might be of limited use even for that one student. // I worry about giving advice based on what might be a synthetic scenario used to avoid revealing the actual nature of your experiment and data; _15 courses,_ really? No wonder 1st semester grades were bad.